# Can't round scroll bar thumb

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm having problems to make a rounded scroll bar thumb. I'm using those CSS properties (main.css):

```
thumb-skin: Embed(source="/resources/images/scrollbar-vert-thumb-fill-default.png");
thumb-up-skin: Embed(source="/resources/images/scrollbar-vert-thumb-top.png");
thumb-over-skin: Embed(source="/resources/images/scrollbar-vert-thumb-fill-hover.png");
thumb-down-skin: Embed(source="/resources/images/scrollbar-vert-thumb-bottom.png"); 
thumb-icon: Embed(source="/resources/images/scrollbar-vert-thumb-icon-default.png");
```

When the scroll is inside a pane or grid, it doesn't get rounded. But if I resize the browser window, it gets rounded.

If I change to a rounded thumb the image 'scrollbar-vert-thumb-fill-default.png', It shows a stretched ugly thumb.

I know that the ber gets stretched depending on the scroll bar size. But is there some different CSS property to help on that? Like a property to set the scroll thumb top, to set it as a rounded top?

Thanks!

Comment: Read something about 9-slice-scaling that seems to help in this case. But the syntax is not allowed in a css file: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: use 9-slice scaling to round the thumb top e botton.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html

Comment: You can _accept_ your own answer by clicking on the tick to the left of your answer. That will show people that it this question has been solved when browsing through their search results.